# Mistic problems when I'm connecting to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, connection

I've been working with some course on "Udemy" about two weeks, and I didn't have any problem till this day. I made a Profile, added a Validation and then when I run the server I have a problem like that:

> (node:9140) DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option { useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.

Guys, do you have any ideas how to solve this problem. I stuck and need your help.

I connect to my database in this way:

```
mongoose
  .connect(db)
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I also tried some recommendations from other topics of StackOverflow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mt79U.png)

My code:

```
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;
```

//Connect to MongoDb

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    db,
    { useNewUrlParser: true }
  )
  .then(() => console.log("MongoDB connected"))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

As my version less than 4, I used the second method, but I still have problems:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bqYF.png)

And it's been working all two weeks.
All versions of node.js and mongodb:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0xBW.png)

My dependencies:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfyGK.png)

Answer (score 1):

The deprecation warning is not a problem, its just a warning for future versions (which will need to be addressed in the future).

As far as i can tell from the picture you posted is that your problem specifically is the statement `res.strtus` at line 83 on the file users.js